# My set tag for aiml does not work

Tags: tags, set, aiml

I am trying to use the set tag in my aiml file but it seems that nothing works. It never match.

color.aiml file

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <aiml version="2.0">
         <category>
           <pattern>IS <set>colors</set> A COLOR</pattern>
           <template>Yes, <star /> is a color.</template>
         </category>

         <category>
           <pattern>IS * A COLOR</pattern>
           <template>No, <star /> is not a color.</template>
         </category>
      </aiml>
```

colors.set file

```
[["red"],["orange"],["yellow"],["green"],["blue"],["indigo"]]
```

The results:

```
Human: Is green a color?
Bot: No, green is not a color.
```

The expected results:

```
Human: Is green a color?
Bot: Yes, green is a color.
```

Could anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: I can help you to do the same with AIML + Python, if you are interested

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same example with below change

Added "**colors.txt**" *file* under "**sets**" *folder* with values like

red

green

blue

green

Answer (score 0):

Your AIML code and set are both correct. I tested it on Pandorabots and it works fine. It appears to be an issue with whatever interpreter you are using or alternatively, you may have a category that is overriding this one in other parts of your AIML.